# Is there a way to "fingerprint" a website visitor without using their IP address or storing a cookie?

Tags: http, http-headers

I'd like to track unique visitors, but of course IP addresses won't help if there are multiple visitors within the same network, and IPs are subject to change.

If possible, I'd like to not store a cookie.

Is there enough information in, say, the HTTP headers or elsewhere that can allow me to determine if the visitor is actually unique? It doesn't have to be completely bulletproof, something simple would suffice.

Comment: This is a complex topic since individuals don't want to be tracked, advertisers would love to track them, and they've been fighting since the internet began. There's no longer a simple solution for this as browsers have followed market demand, including better anti-fingerprinting techniques. (There's also laws about not collecting personally identifying information. Such a fingerprint is likely to be considered personally identifying depending on how well it can track a specific browser instance.)

Comment: @Ouroborus Thanks for the reply. I hadn't thought about it that way but I suppose you're right. I guess I will have to use a cookie

Comment: You might be better off using a product like Google Analytics. It can track unique users well enough for statistical analysis and provides the metrics in a way that avoids the anti-tracking laws. (Assuming you have the required notices in place; GA helps with that.)

Comment: @Ouroborus That's a good suggestion. Really I'm just trying to keep track of users because my website is about to be slightly gamified to decrease bounce rate. I don't want them to lose their progress, but don't want them to have to make an account. It's not gamified to the degree that it would be a big problem for them if they do lose their progress, but I just didn't want to have to put a cookie warning up